# Option to have the employer field being a select with existing orgs?

Tags: caldera-forms

I want to let members of existing organisations register themselves via CF.

If I let them free type their own organisation name, it's sure they will type the name in very creative ways, that are going to be different than how they are created in CiviCRM and therefore adding duplicates

In the drupal world with webform, you can limit what can be put in the organisation name and instead of a free form, have a select

Is there something similar with CF? having the employer field not a free form but a select with the list of organisations being a select of all the organisations in a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contact reference field in caldera forms limiting the entries to a group created containing the employers should work.